# Changing the position of div with dynamic react-pose, react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, redux

I've cobbled together this little sandbox to demonstrate: https://codesandbox.io/s/64xv97y45n

The purple div in the upper left hand corner is supposed to move as letters are typed. When a letter is typed, the `currIndex` (the currently active box) value on the redux store is incremented or decremented accordingly. The reducer then uses `currIndex` to compute the `currentCoords` or the div's new absolute position (for the purposes of attached sandbox, 'slightly more to the right'). The `currentCoords` store property is then passed on as a prop to control the dynamic pose of the purple `div`. But the div refuses to update its pose. Redux DevTools tells me `currentCoords` is updating properly, or at least well enough for it to move a little. What's wrong?

Relevant logic:

```
 const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "KEYPRESS":
          return {
            ...state,
            number: [...state.number, action.key],
            currIndex: ++state.currIndex,
            currentCoords: state.boxCoords[state.currIndex]
          };

<SNIP>

const Cursor = posed.div({
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: ({ xPos }) => xPos,
    y: ({ yPos }) => yPos
  },

  hidden: {
    opacity: 0
  }
});

<SNIP>



<Cursor
            className="cursor"
            initialPose="visible"
            xPos={this.props.currentCoords.x}
            yPos={this.props.currentCoords.y}
          />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving div by passing redux state to dynamic react-pose props in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862829/moving-div-by-passing-redux-state-to-dynamic-react-pose-props-in-react)